# B2B Commerce cloud

Tags: customer-community, b2b-commerce, cloudcraze

My client has procured B2b commerce-cloudcraze and while going through the documentation of cloudcraze .I understand that the storefront will be hosted on salesforce communities. We already are using a customer community, can I use the same community for hosting/configuring the default storefront or i would need to have a separate community for storefront.

On the flipside can i customize the storefront in cloudcraze and include my own custom lightning components/screens

Comment: no, you can't add you custom lightning component to cc's storefront. It uses VF and can be configured wich storefronts components to display. for the example search box and other.  you have to write components for your own community, that uses on a backside objects and data model of CC. Also, CC provides its API  (managed apex classes )to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We went with a separate community for the store, I think that the documentation was very unclear about if it was able to run in a community with other community sites. I came to the conclusion that it is best to keep it separated. B2B Commerce (CloudCraze) is not built with lightning components.

They have their own components that you can built, they also have their own APIs that you can use for that. To add a component to a page you would have to override that page (clone it and add your code/component) this adds a bit of complexity when upgrading to a newer version B2B Commerce.